# Upgrading from SRAM Force AXS to Force AXS WIDE - What can I keep?

Tags: sram, gravel

As the title already says, I own right now a Force eTap AXS. However, I do sometimes need a wider range, since I like driving off rad steep climbs, therefore I'd like to upgrade to the AXS Wide. Do I need to buy everything new (of course, not the brakes) or can I keep, for example the crankset? I am not interested in fitting bigger tires, 45mm is just fine for me.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

According to the information in [this article on bikepacking](https://bikepacking.com/gear/sram-force-axs-wide/), the 10-36t cassette fits on the XDR driver and is compatible with all current 1x and 2x AXS drivetrain components with the caveat that a 36t Max AXS rear derailleur must be used. It seems the wide range cassette and the appropriately spec'd rear derailleur are the only additions a current AXS groupset owner needs to increase the gearing range.

It's good you are happy with the 45mm wide tires, because that happens to be the limit even with the WIDE version of the AXS crankset.  Obviously SRAM specs are conservative if you are currently running wide tires with narrow version of the AXS crank.